# VBA to create alternating tabs in excel

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am really new to code so excuse the simple question:

I currently have the below code which creates new tabs in excel from a list which works perfectly, however I now have a 'template 2' and I would like it to create template 1 then template 2 for each item in the 'input' tab using range F8 for 'template 1' and G8 for 'template 2'. I can get it to do all the items in F8 for template 1 and then all the items in G8 for template 2 but I cant manage to get it to alternate.

I ultimately want to create template 1 then template 2, copy and paste values into an new file and save, then repeat for the next line down in the input tab.

Thank you in advance

```
Sub Addnewsheets()

Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Sheets("Input").Range("F8")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

For Each MyCell In MyRange
Sheets("Template 1").Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value 'Renames the new worksheets
Next MyCell
Worksheets("End").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If I interpret your issue correctly, just add these two lines before the `Next MyCell`

```
Sheets("Template 2").Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Offset(, 1).Value 'Renames the new worksheets based on column G
```

For clarity sake, the `For Loop` becomes:

```
For Each MyCell In MyRange
    Sheets("Template 1").Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value 'Renames the new worksheets
    Sheets("Template 2").Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Offset(, 1).Value 'Renames the new worksheets based on column G
Next MyCell
```

Comment: @AmyF - please mark as answered (green check mark top left of answer) so that others in the future know it was solved.